# Webpack bundling problems on a simple socket.io server

Tags: javascript, webpack, socket.io, babeljs

I'm setting up a simple `socket.io` server without express:

**`index.js`**

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const host = "localhost";
const port = 3000;

const io = new Server(port, { /* options */ });


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on('connected', msg => {
        console.log("Socket connected");
    });

    socket.on('disconnected', msg => {
        console.log("Socket disconnected");
    });

    socket.on('upload', msg => {
        console.log("Upload: " + JSON.stringify(msg));

        io.emit("download", "Reply: " + JSON.stringify(msg));
    });
});
  
console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://${host}:${port}/`);
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "socketio",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "socketio",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "build": "webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundle'),
    filename: 'qedgesocket.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When issuing `yarn start` it runs fine, but when building the bundle `yarn build` I'm getting a ton of errors:

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.js
assets by status 302 KiB [cached] 1 asset
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
javascript modules 451 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/engine.io/ 110 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/ws/ 115 KiB 14 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/*.js 109 KiB 8 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/negotiator/ 17.4 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/cjs/ 14.2 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/socket.io-parser/build/cjs/*.js 14.9 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/debug/src/*.js 12 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/ 14.3 KiB 2 modules
  + 11 modules
json modules 145 KiB
  ./node_modules/socket.io/package.json 1.81 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/mime-db/db.json 143 KiB [built] [code generated]

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/buffer-util.js 113:23-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js 31:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 3:18-44
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

WARNING in ./node_modules/ws/lib/validation.js 117:24-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utf-8-validate' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/sender.js 11:30-53
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 8:19-42
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

2 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

ERROR in ./node_modules/base64id/lib/base64id.js 9:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/base64id/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js 10:35-54
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 45:17-36 813:15-34
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js 16:14-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/mime-types'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./node_modules/accepts/index.js 16:11-32
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 33:16-34
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/permessage-deflate.js 3:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js 14:26-57
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 3:18-44
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js 3:21-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 7:21-46
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/sender.js 5:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 8:19-42
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/sender.js 6:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 8:19-42
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/sender.js 7:27-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 8:19-42
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/stream.js 3:19-36
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 5:34-57
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js 6:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 6:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js 7:14-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 6:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js 8:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 6:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js 9:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 6:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js 10:23-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 6:19-52
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 3:18-44
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js 11:21-38
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 3:18-44
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js 12:16-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/ws/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ws/index.js 3:18-44
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-adapter/dist/index.js 7:18-31
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 42:28-56
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 4:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/server.js 4:11-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 5:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/server.js 5:14-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 5:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/socket.js 6:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify") }'
    - install 'timers-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "timers": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 13:15-34
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports-uws/polling.js 5:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build/transports-uws'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports-uws/index.js 3:18-38
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/userver.js 6:25-52
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 11:16-36
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports/polling-jsonp.js 5:11-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build/transports'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports/index.js 4:24-50
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 7:16-45
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports/polling.js 5:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/engine.io/build/transports'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/transports/index.js 3:18-38
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io/build/engine.io.js 7:16-45
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 36:20-40
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/client.js 6:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 37:17-36
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 30:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 31:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 32:15-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 34:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 35:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

ERROR in ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/uws.js 8:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/md/dev/socketio/node_modules/socket.io/dist'
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js 48:14-30
 @ ./src/index.js 1:15-35

34 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 34 errors and 3 warnings in 3376 ms
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Should I need more than `babel-loader` for such a simple code? Why it is complaining for the `node_modules` code as it is expliciting being excluded? How to make this simple project works?